# 'function' object is not subscriptable in local package

Tags: python-3.x, package, python-module

While trying to learn how Python modules and packages work, I have the following error that I can't find a way around:

```
$ ./myMain.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myMain.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(foobar.getKey['A'])
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

My directory structure is the following:

```
.
├── myMain.py*
└── utils/
    └── Foo/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__/
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
        │   └── foobar.cpython-36.pyc
        └── foobar.py
```

and `myMain.py` would be the main script from where the package would be imported. `myMain.py` has the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from utils.Foo import foobar

print(foobar.getKey['A'])
```

`__init__.py` is an empty file, and `foobar.py` has the function definition:

```
TEST_DICT = {
        'A': 'This is A',
        'B': 'This is B'
}

def getKey(letter):
    return TEST_DICT[letter]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

After trying to run the code in `myMain.py` from within the Python interpret, I realised that the function call was writen with wrong syntax. Instead of `foobar.getKey['A']` one should have instead `foobar.getKey('A')` because we are calling the function and not the dictionary object.